# Angular Controllers: How are these magic methods working in this unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the two snippets of code below, taken from [the angular docs on unit testing](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing):

> In angular the controllers are strictly separated from the DOM manipulation logic which results in a much easier testability story as can be seen in this example:

```
function PasswordCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.password = '';
  $scope.grade = function() {
    var size = $scope.password.length;
    if (size > 8) {
      $scope.strength = 'strong';
    } else if (size > 3) {
      $scope.strength = 'medium';
    } else {
      $scope.strength = 'weak';
    }
  };
}
```

> and the test is straight forward

```
var pc = new PasswordCtrl();
pc.password('abc');
pc.grade();
expect(pc.strength).toEqual('weak');
```

I want to know how the 2nd code snippet is working.  No mock $scope is passed to it, and yet apparently it works.  Also the method calls `pc.password('abc');` and `pc.grade()` seem to be aliases for `$scope.password('abc')` and `$scope.grade()`, but where do these aliases come from?  Is this something built into angular?  A sort of equivalent to ruby's method_missing?  If so, how does it work under the hood?

Comment: are you sure that this test works? Could you provide live example in plunker? It feels fishy.

Comment: It's from the official angular docs, as I linked to in the OP, so I assume it works.  They don't give details about how to set it up, so I haven't tried running it myself.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, also, i see you wrote a soon-to-be-released book on angular, so if you have recommendations for other tutorials on unit testing in angular, i'd appreciate them.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible this code is from pre-1.0 days, where you could access scope directly on an instance of a controller.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not work as is.  I get the following error if I simply paste what you have here into 2 files and tell karma to run it.  Error, as expected, is:

```
Chrome 26.0 (Mac) ERROR
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'password' of undefined
    at /Volumes/.../utest/test/ctrl.js:2 Chrome
26.0 (Mac): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.173 secs / 0 secs)
```

where `ctrl.js:2` is:

```
  $scope.password = '';
```

The AngularJS documentation is unfortunately not clear.  All the test must take place inside a `describe` block and therefore the documentation must have assumed that the reader know to mock the $scope needed in a `beforeEach` block.

Comment: This is unhelpful and does not answer the question.  I highly doubt the official angular docs are wrong.  It's far more likely that you do not understand how the example is intended to be implemented, which in itself is no crime since the docs are not clear.  But still it does not appear that you understand them either so this doesn't qualify as an answer to my question.

Comment: I guess what I hoped to convey is that the code does not work as it.  Your question is: "I want to know how the 2nd code snippet is working. No mock $scope is passed to it, and yet apparently it works."  And the answer is: No, you do have to mock $scope.  I will make that clear in the answer.

Comment: If that is your claim, then there is an implied followup question: Why would the docs have an example that doesn't work?  What is required to make it work?  The claim that the official angular docs have a completely wrong example that makes no sense at all requires evidence and an explanation.

Comment: Your edit does not address the question either.  Even if we assume they just to forgot to include "$scope" in the controller constructor, what about the password() function?  Is that setter function automatically created for any property?

Comment: Good catch.  I think you just identified an error in their documentation.  It make no sense for pc.password to be a function yet in the controller it is initialised as an empty string and in the grade function it check for the length.