# How to use directive inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use a `counter` http://plnkr.co/edit/eRWPuEP8LdQBbHksIL3S?p=info directive inside ng-repeat 
like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div counter value="item" min="1" max="30" step="3" editable></div>
</div>
```

in my controller

```
$scope.items = []
items.push(1);
items.push(2);
```

But it is not working.

Edit:1

in my controller

```
$scope.items = []
$scope.items.push(1);
$scope.items.push(2);
```

Edit 2:

My Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/ji2ppBp0PyRCzAT4UhMj?p=preview

Comment: `$scope.items.push(1)`... Could you post a plnkr of your attempt?

Comment: Yeah ,It was `$scope.items.push(1)` I write it mistakenly. But directive is not working inside ng-repeat

Comment: i tried it in the plunkr above and its working there.

Comment: yes, above plunkr is working but not inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: @EmptyData Could you show us the plnkr where you actually tried it?

Comment: @JLRishe I have added my plunkr above http://plnkr.co/edit/ji2ppBp0PyRCzAT4UhMj?p=preview

Comment: it looks like the binding inside the directive isn't two way.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO post][1]

Possibly a duplicate question

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502559/angular-js-using-a-directive-inside-an-ng-repeat-and-a-mysterious-power-of-sco

Comment: @RaphaelMüller, it's 2-way binding, but just can't change a primitive type value in parent scope.

Comment: @EmptyData, could you pls also upvote my answer if it's helpful to you, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-repeat creates a child scope, `item` is passed to the child scope as a primitive type. even you isolates the scope in your directive with 2-way binding for `value`, the value will not be changed, ie. `scope.items` is always `[1, 2]`

solution is to pass an object (reference) to child scope, to achieve this:

```
$scope.items = []
$scope.items.push({val:1});
$scope.items.push({val:2});

// template of counter directive
<input type="text" class="counter-field" ng-model="value.val">

var setValue = function( val ) {
    scope.value.val = parseInt( val );
};
```

you might also need to change `minus` and `plus` methods to refer to `scope.value.val`