# Getting DOM element in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I´m trying to get a DOM element in order to change it inside a AngularJS1.0.6 directive.

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars" data-highlight="{{car.id}}">
```

Directive:

```
var iw = angular.element(document.querySelector('#iw-' + id));
console.log("iw=" + iw);
```

Please see the plunker for details: https://plnkr.co/edit/dP2cvut4f5ao5pFe6ka0?p=preview

Comment: Please be more specific what you need to accomplish. Not sure why you would need to use dom query approach

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make it easy. What I need to do is to change the infowindow Google Maps background color with the user fires the event on mouseover the list of cars.

Comment: This makes sense, but just replacing the order of the boat-map and the list in the html does not work. Any idea how to do accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little research, I was able to make it work. Basically first issue comes when you use directive inside ng-repeat (also directive). 
In this case directive's scope must be set for example like: `scope: {car: '=highlight'}`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502559/using-a-directive-inside-an-ng-repeat-and-a-mysterious-power-of-scope) can desribe what happens. I would rather use `<ul highlight="cars"></ul>` along with directive's template like `'<ul><li ng-repeat="car in cars"></li></ul>'`. So ng-repeat would be inside directive.

When you get through, another issue comes in form of syncing two directives (different scopes). You need DOM ready to select element from another directive. I saved your compliled element to car object - it can be count as workaround that make it easier.

[Forked plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZFA1Wwj1OyzKb1LbGtx4?p=preview)

Comment: You are a beast!

Answer (score -1):

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars track by $index" data-highlight="{{car.$index}}">
```

or

if whatever property exists, in your case, `car` must have `id` property